# How to add belongs_to to the same table in two different columns?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I have a users table and tasks table and I want to have a schema for task table which has from_id and to_id like.

```
belongs_to(:user, TaskTracker2.Accounts.User, foreign_key: :from_id)
belongs_to(:user, TaskTracker2.Accounts.User, foreign_key: :to_id)
```

But it raise an argument error, how to do it in the right way?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a unique value in the first argument. Something like

```
belongs_to(:user_from, TaskTracker2.Accounts.User, foreign_key: :from_id)
belongs_to(:user_to, TaskTracker2.Accounts.User, foreign_key: :to_id)
```

Comment: Oh, yes, thank you very much, I just thought the first argument is the schema's name so I did not change it. But it isn't of course (schema's name is users, anyway).